# Transform JSON data into different format

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have my original data is in the standard json format as mentioned below:

```
var data = ["chat1", "chat2"]
```

and i want it to be transformed into different format as below:

```
var newData = {chat1 : o.chat1, chat2: o.chat2 , mydates : []}
```

I am stuck with my codes :

```js
var data = ["chat1", "chat2"]

var v = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  v.push({
    data[i]: o.data[i],
    ques: []
  })
}
console.log(v)
```

Comment: where did the `o` object come from, please make the expected output more clear

Answer (score 0):

A couple of mistakes

- Instead of `push`, you need to **assign** the property to an object
- Instead of `o.data[i]`, you need to use `o[data[i]]`

i.e.

```
v[data[i]] = o[data[i]]
```

**Finally**

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
{
    v[data[i]] = o[data[i]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `ES6`, it should be:

```js
var data = ["chat1", "chat2"]
var o = { chat1: 'xxx', chat2: 'yyy', other: 'zzz'};

var newData = Object.assign({  mydates : [] }, ...data.map(prop => ({[prop]: o[prop]})));
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

`data[i]` is not a valid name. You want something like this

```js
var data = ["chat1", "chat2"]

var v = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=2) {
  v.push({
    "ques": []
  });
  v[v.length - 1][data[i]] = "o." + data[i];
  i++
  v[v.length - 1][data[i]] = "o." + data[i];
}
console.log(v)
```

OR if you have something else called `o`:

```js
var data = ["chat1", "chat2"], o={"chat1": "something1","chat2":"something2"};

var v = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=2) {
  v.push({
    "ques": []
  });
  v[v.length - 1][data[i]] = o[data[i]];
  i++
  v[v.length - 1][data[i]] = o[data[i]];
}
console.log(v)
```

Comment: I completely agree with your point, but i need that answer should not contain (" " ) inverted commas

Comment: For that i am trying using Regex

Comment: I do not understand your comment about double quotes. The quotes in the name part are inserted by the browser. That is how to make valid JS Objects and strings

Comment: I agree with your point but the above snippet is a subroutine call. however, the output of this function will be the input of other function

Comment: So create a [mcve] so we have a chance to figure out what you want instead of what you think you want ([X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))